# Other tran transpiling to JS, does google dart compile to object code?

Tags: dart

Google dart compiles to javascript code but dart is also a standalone language. I know Dart can also run without javascript (on the vm), but to what does it compile to? Does it compile to C or object code? I couldnt find any information about it.

Im also asking because dart works on mobile devices and ive also read it will be used in some experimental OS called fuchsia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know
it's compiled to binary code on-the-fly in the VM,
it's compiled to binary code ahead of time with AoT.